# Find out which MySQL/MariaDB user/database/table is causing high CPU usage

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cpu-usage

We have a lot of apps using different databases running on our server. The mariadb process is using like 85% of the CPU currently which is really high. We want to find out where we could try and optimize things. Is it somehow possible to track CPU usage by db user, database or table? (the more finegrained the better obviously, but even something like % per user would already help a lot)
MySQL slow query log is already running with not many results. We've also tried doing `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` when CPU is spiking and looking at CPU_TIME in the user statistics, but it hasn't really been of much help.

Comment: its probably more a question of which user is responsible. you may find some info in the process info. on linux: `ps aux | grep sql`

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide speed suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

When having the userstat plugin enabled you can find CPU usage information per user in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USER_STATISTICS table. See

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-statistics/

and

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-user_statistics-table/

Comment: CPU_TIME is not CPU usage though, right? Maybe im misunderstanding that field

Comment: @nn3112337 Could you post TEXT results example from your system for one user?  information_schema.user_statistics table.Thanks.

Comment: this is after running userstat for ~1 minute: https://pastebin.com/NwzwGNdH

Comment: The relevant server code is  ```end_cpu_time= my_getcputime();
  end_utime=    microsecond_interval_timer();
  busy_time= (end_utime - start_utime) / 1000000.0;
  cpu_time=  (end_cpu_time - start_cpu_time) / 10000000.0;```
. So the busy time is the actual time spent on running queries in seconds, and the cpu_time is the real CPU usage time spent in seconds (which does not include io_wait time etc.)

Comment: @nn3112337 The content of TABLE_STATISTICS would be more helpful to identify which database and table is most used on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the slowlog and have `long_query_time` set rather low.

A few hours later, use `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t` to summarize the output file.

Note:  The slowlog records elapsed time, not CPU time.  But generally elapsed it more important than CPU.  And there is a correlation between the two.

More:  [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)